# Strapi unable to find relation

Tags: strapi

Due to running some manual queries all relations of database are deleted but when i try to rebuild strapi
It is not recreating relations on tables. I tried to set forceMigration and runningMigration to true and then run the application
but still it is not creating relations. Error Message on different component is

```
UPDATE "salesforce"."components_pages_main_nesteds_components" as a
            SET "order" = b.src_order
            FROM ( select "id", row_number() over (partition by "entity_id" order by "order") as src_order from "components_pages_main_nesteds_components" where "entity_id" = $1 ) AS b
            WHERE b.id = a.id - relation "components_pages_main_nesteds_components" does not exist
error: UPDATE "salesforce"."components_pages_main_nesteds_components" as a
            SET "order" = b.src_order
            FROM ( select "id", row_number() over (partition by "entity_id" order by "order") as src_order from "components_pages_main_nesteds_components" where "entity_id" = $1 ) AS b
            WHERE b.id = a.id - relation "components_pages_main_nesteds_components" does not exist
```

Answer (score 0):

When creating relationships in Strapi, it is necessary to add the relationship in the intermediate tables. Strapi establishes relationships between all tables through intermediate tables. For example, if I have a user related to a category, there will be a table called 'user_category_links' to add the relationship. By doing this, there is no need to enforce anything.